# Django form error

Tags: django, forms

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Job
```

That was my form, now trying to save it will raise an exception, and trying to validate it just fails with no errors....

```
job = get_object_or_404(models.Job, pk=1)
form = forms.JobForm(instance = job)
try:
    form.save()
except:
    print sys.exc_info()

#=>(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'JobForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'",), <traceback object at 0x1029dbb48>)
```

Tried to validate it:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
else:
    print 'error'
    print form.errors, len(form.errors)
#=> 'error' 
#=> 0
```

So the form isn't valid, but the there are no errors!
Any idea?

Comment: would be nice to see Job model and actual data that gets posted

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your form is definitely not bound. Read about [Bound and Unbound forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms).

From that documentation:

> To bind data to a form, pass the data as a **dictionary** as the **first parameter** to your **Form class constructor**.

That means that also the change of a field in your model doesn't make the form bound. You have to pass those values explicitly via the constructor. But:

> Note that passing an **empty dictionary** creates a **bound form** with empty data

and consider this

> If you have a bound Form instance and want to change the data somehow, or if you want to **bind an unbound Form** instance to some data, **create another Form instance**. There is no way to change data in a Form instance. Once a Form instance has been created, you should consider its data **immutable**, whether it has data or not.

If you validate an **unbound** form:

> It's meaningless to validate a form with no data, but, for the record, here's what happens with unbound forms:
>
> `>>> f = ContactForm()`
>   `>>> f.is_valid()`
>   `False`
>   `>>> f.errors
>
>   {}`

Comment: I'm passing `request.POST` to my form, and there is definitely data being sent. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Saved me so much time, I was getting a validation error but nothing in the errors.  This absolutely answered why.

Comment: You can also use `f.errors.as_data()` to show errors, in a better format

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that you can't save a model form that has only been created with instance data (I just tried doing this with one of my forms and got the exact same error) because a form doesn't become a bound form until you pass in extra information.  It doesn't really make sense to only provide data that already exists on the model to a form (and then save it again) as there wouldn't be any change.  If this is coming from an html form, you should also be passing in request.POST (or request.GET) to the form.

Comment: The documentation has an example that just retrieves the model and pass to the form and then saves the form http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method , specifically after this comment # Create a form to edit an existing Article.  Anyway I tried what you suggested by doing job.state = 'RUNNING', then passed it to the form but the same error happened. I'm using urllib2 to send that POST request anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure why they provide that as an example (at least saving it), because it doesn't seem possible.  To save the form, you'll need to provide the POST dictionary as the first parameter.  In order to save the form, is_bound and is_valid() should both return True.

Comment: The documentation has been updated to remove the incorrect example.